# How python multiprocessing works?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to know how multiprocessing works.

Does this mean I can run `8 separate process` simultaneously, if I have `8 core CPU` ?

For example here is my processor information.

```
giri@ubuntu:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2294.762
BogoMIPS:              4589.52
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

Here is my cpuinfo

```
giri@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x23
cpu MHz     : 2294.762
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4589.52
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

As you can see, my number of CPU(s) is `1`.

Does this mean multiprocessing is useless in my situation?

Comment: If this is a hyperthreaded CPU, then you'll still be able to run two processes simultaneously. But in general, you will be able to run simultaneously, as many processes as you have logical core CPUs on your machine. I would assume that you have a hyperthreaded CPU in this case, so multiprocessing shouldn't be _useless_ - just not _as useful_

Comment: please show us also `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: well I guess you're in a virtual machine that has only one core assigned to you, so it doesn't make sense to run multiple heavy processes or threads in parallel.

Comment: @Pavel Thats my ubuntu desktop cpu details. I'm not on a virtual machine

Comment: hm, that's strange - a i3-2350M should have two cores shown in `/proc/cpuinfo` (4 because of HT, actually)

Comment: @Pavel hmm. Thats weird. No idea why its showing like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run N thread simultaneously if you have N cores (if threads per core = 1). Though if you try to run more threads than you have processors, the operating system will run your threads one after the other by small 'slices' and they will seem to run in parallel.
So multi threading will not allow your code to be faster in this case, but it's often interesting, you can for instance have a thread waiting for the disk to reply while another waits for the network and a third one runs...
i3-2350M should be 2 cores / 2 threads per core, so 4 threads running at the same time.

Comment: Hmm. Thank.. So If I buy 4 core processor, does that mean I can run 16 threads? When you mean "thread" you are not talking about multi threading right?

Comment: I am talking about multi threading, a thread is a 'sequence of instructions' in a process (two threads in the same process share the memory space). A process has at least one thread. On my current laptop, I have 4 cores (two threads by core) able to run 8 threads simultaneously, though 'ps -ef | wc' shows I currently have 266 processes. Multi threading is a programming technique where you create several threads to handle a problem, they will all run in parallel (really in parallel if you have enough cores, apparently in parallel if not).

Comment: A thread usually spend most of its time waiting for a resource (disk, network, other I/O, lock, ...) so the real number of threads using the cpu at the same time is often still small. Tools such as nmon or vmstat can show you this ('r' in vmstat).

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your time Nicolas